# Is it possible to flash UEFI(bios) from usb without entering UEFI shell?

Tags: boot, motherboard, bios, uefi

The other day I decided to flash my ASUS g75vw laptop's UEFI(aka new bios) with a new version. 
Something went wrong and after restart I can only see black screen.
I can say that the laptop starts, keyboard lights up and cpu fan working but UEFI seems to be stuck at something, apparently due to bad flashing.

My question is it possible to re-flash my motherboard's UEFI(I can't access UEFI shell) or should I just order a new motherboard?

Comment: If your UEFI/BIOS is bricked and there's no way to recover (jumper? recovery BIOS?) then you may be out of luck...

Comment: I second that ^^

Answer (score 0):

I realize that this response is a bit late but are you going to be doing this kind of thing often? I suggest investing in a Dediprog SF100 then.
http://www.dediprog.com/pd/spi-flash-solution/sf100

You could also use a much cheaper device, Bus Pirate, to flash the BIOS as well. 
http://dangerousprototypes.com/docs/Bus_Pirate

FlashROM can then be used to interface with either of those programmers to program SPI flash memory(BIOS NV memory). I have personally used both with good results.

In short, the only way to restore UEFI while in the state that you are in, is to flash a new UEFI ROM image to SPI flash on your motherboard.

Your motherboard manufacturer should be able to provide you with a full UEFI ROM image.